# PHP - go to Next or Previous file in directory

Tags: php, directory, pagination, filemtime

We're making a portfolio with pages in a directory like:

```
/portfolio/a-company-name.php  
/portfolio/another-company-name.php  
/portfolio/yet-another-company-name.php
```

We want to build "next" and "previous" links on each page, where people can navigate to the next or previous page in the directory. Any ideas?

I would think the only little snag might occur on the first and last files in the directory. So I guess there'd have to be an "if statement" of some sort to only build next/previous link if there's actually a next/previous file in the directory. Or, even better, to where it would just endlessly loop....for example if you were on the last file in the directory, and the "next" link would simply go to the first file.

Comment: i would not being using one file per 'company' one file a db look up etc is the better approach - if your just starting out i suggest looking in to a free CMS

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all PHP files in the directory with the [glob function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and save them to an array.
2. Next, by the name of the current file, find its index in the file array and increase by 1 to get the name of the next file.

```
$page = dirname(__FILE__) . '/portfolio'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'.php';

$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/portfolio/*.php');

$currentIdx = array_search($page, $files);

$nextIdx = $currentIdx + 1;

if (isset($files[$nextIdx]))
{
    $nextFile = $files[$nextIdx];
    $next = pathinfo($nextFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo 'Next file: <a href="'.$next.'">'.$next.'</a>';
}
else 
{
    echo "No next file";
}
```

Previous similarly:

```
$page = dirname(__FILE__) . '/portfolio'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'.php';
$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/portfolio/*.php');
$currentIdx = array_search($page, $files);
$prevIdx = $currentIdx - 1;
if (isset($files[$prevIdx])) {
    $prevFile = $files[$prevIdx];
    $prev = pathinfo($prevFile,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo 'Previous file: <a href="'.$prev.'">'.$prev.'</a>';
} else {
    echo "No previous file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this function `scandir()`. This will get all the files in a directory in an array. So you can loop through that or select the next file when you want too.
`Documentation:`http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php